# subdomain_routes gem with DEPRECATION WARNING: Kernel#returning has been deprecated in favor of Object#tap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, subdomain

We use subdomain_routes (0.3.1) and now we're seeing this deprecation warning when going from rails 2.3.8 to rails 2.3.14:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Kernel#returning has been deprecated in favor of Object#tap. (called from significant_keys_with_subdomains at /home/mei/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2314/gems/subdomain_routes-0.3.1/lib/subdomain_routes/routes.rb:75)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

BTW, here is the code for significant_keys_with_subdomains:

```
def significant_keys_with_subdomains
  returning significant_keys_without_subdomains do |result|
    if conditions[:subdomains].is_a? Symbol
      result << conditions[:subdomains]
      result.uniq!
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use one of the existing forks that fix it or just create your own and do what this person did: https://github.com/mataki/subdomain_routes/commit/aed6b45d0e98531bdd4201e8f076bf49a34eadf8?w=1

Comment: Thanks for the link to mataki's modifications. They got rid of the warnings.

Comment: It turned out the modifications got rid of the warnings, but didn't work.

Comment: There are probably other commits that you'll need too. I would just go to rubygems.org and search for the plugin. You will find other forks that you can try.